# C# call different list that have sequential naming

Tags: c#, list

I know this is a noob question but I need a way to simplify a method

I need to call different list sequentially based on their name

for example: the list are

- Lx1
- Lx2
- Lx3

etc

How can I achieve this?
I need to do this dynamically

Comment: Call how? Please explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Show some code. This question is unclear.

Comment: Pass the list as parameter? `MyMethod(Lx1); MyMethod(Lx2); MyMethod(Lx3);` Define the Method like: `private void MyMethod(List<string> list) { }`

Comment: it is variety of list each containing different values and there will be more list created as needed. i need to iterate through all of these list. i was hoping to run a for loop through all the names of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names are of little use at runtime, so the fact that your lists are named sequentially wouldn't help you access them.

If you would like to access something by index, add it to an array or a collection that supports indexing, e.g. a list. If you are accessing lists by index, then your collection becomes a list of lists:

```
var listOfLists = new List<List<string>> {Lx1, Lx2, Lx3};
```

Now you can access `Lx1` as `listOfLists[0]`, `Lx2` as `listOfLists[1]`, and so on.

Comment: is there any way i can get the list name dynamically and not staticlaly?

Comment: @StephenVanSittert There's no "list name", only "variable name". You cannot create a new variable dynamically. If you get rid of variable names, you could make a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` and use strings as list names.